# What's going on in this electric panel?

Tags: electrical-panel

I toured a home with an inspector and found out that, while the two prong outlets have been "updated" with three prong outlets, very few in the home are grounded. I am attaching a picture of the electric panel to find out if there is grounding at the panel. I've done quite a bit of reading to find out that you can ground the outlets if the panel is grounded. [image: ElectricPanel]

Comment: The cables appear to have ground wires, which appear to be grounded. There's some incorrect stuff going on with the neutrals appearing to share holes with grounds, *unless* that's just the angle of the picture making it look that way, but really they have their own holes and the bar in back makes it look that way. But I think I see actual hole-sharing (which can be OK for grounds, is not OK for Neutrals.)

Comment: Obviously that panel is full.  If you are considering purchasing this property you may want to budget in a panel upgrade.

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on the inside of the panel's door please?  Also, can you get us photos of the insides of some of the receptacle boxes?

Comment: That panel, even though stuffed to the gills, is modern enough to be properly grounded. From the pic it's hard to tell, but there appears to be a 4ga or 6ga bare copper near the center bottom of the pic, which would be a ground wire, presumably properly connected to a Ufer or ground rod(s) The large white wire on the left side is your neutral.   Not sure what's going on with the braided AL wire on the left. Like @jwh20 said, a panel upgrade would be good. Obviously there have been numerous additions and changes over the years.

Comment: Meant to add:  Grounding, connected to the neutral (bonded) has been required for many decades almost since the beginning. The physics of a grounded neutral conductor is what makes all this work!  and in the last 50-60 years or so (not sure of the timeline), the separate Equipment Grounding Conductor makes it even more safe.

Comment: I see a lot of panels, and that one has far less problems than most.  I don't even see one alien breaker (it's a GE panel, right?)  The wires are very cluttered but there's nothing wrong with that, and that's mostly because you have an old-school "narrow gutter" panel.  New panels are 14" wide because UL changed the standard to provide for wire bending radius.  All that extra wire length will be rather important if you upgrade panels - and for rearranging breakers generally.